# How to return count students grouped by age from google app engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am totally new to Google App Engine, I am using Python and I have created model for student
with name and year and I have stored records. How to return count students grouped by age ?

```
for example 
25 years old    12 students
18 years old    125 students
```

and so on ...

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb


class StudentModel(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)
    age = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: As an aside you normally wouldn't store age in an entity, next year it will be wrong.  You should store their birthdate.

Comment: @TimHoffman It is just a test project to learn something, but I stuck with group by in gae

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `distinct=True` or `group_by=['age']` to fetch unique ages first, and then count them async. But the best way for big datasets is to store&update this number somewhere on each put.

```
ages = StudentModel.query(projection=['age'], distinct=True).fetch()

counts = {}
for age in ages:
  # query to get num of students for each age
  counts[age.age] = StudentModel.query(StudentModel.age == age.age).count_async()

# get result for each counter
for c in counts:
  counts[c] = counts[c].get_result()

for age in counts:
  print '%s years old \t %s students' % (age, counts[age])
```

Answer (score 3):

Unless you keep a running total when you add entities you will need to perform a query across all entities.  The simplest/niave way will be just use `map` method of the query to add age to a `collections.Counter` http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html

```
from collection import Counter
c = Counter()

def count(x):
   c[x.age]+=1

result = StudentModel.query().map(count)
```

`c` is dictionary with the aggregate of all ages with the age the key in the dict. `result` will contain a list of None values, if you want each entity in result as well count function would return the `x`.

If you have large numbers of entities/and try to do this in a front facing request it could easily take a long time and result in a DeadlineExceededError.  If your entities are large, then a projection query may be a bit faster.

Comment: correct import is : `from collections import Counter` (add `s`)

Answer (score 2):

The answer above will only work for very small datasets. For large datasets you will need to use something like mapreduce, else you should have used cloud sql which support grouping and agregations, instead of the datastore.